# How to use Mojarra and PrimeFaces in the same application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I am creating a JSF Application in which I am using Mojarra 2.1.3 (javax.faces.jar) as implementation jar. I want to display a DataTable with Pagination support when it retrieves Data from Database. I have been advised to use Primefaces along with Mojarra. My question is how and where to place both the Mojarra and Primefaces jar in my JSF Application and what related configuration I need to do. Also how to call Mojarra and Primefaces specific tags in the same application, I mean how to do the segregation in my Facelets page.

Answer (score 3):

Modern Java application servers usually come with Mojarra bundled. You don't need to add it to your project manually.

If you work with an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse just configure the server for the IDE, create a new Java Web or Java EE project and all necessary libs are added to your project automatically. I recommend to walk through one of the quick start tutorials [for Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html) or [Eclipse](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html).

If you are required to use a specific Mojarra version, check your application servers's documentation and replace the server's JSF jar files (jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jar) if nececssary.

Primefaces is not bundled with application servers. You have to add it to your project manually. A good starting point is the [Primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html). Too keep it short: put the primefaces jar file in the classpath of your web project (usually WEB-INF/lib).

You can use Primefaces and JSF tags side by side in your facelets. You only need to add the correct namespace definition, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  ...
</html>
```

(For Primefaces versions before 3.0, the namespace definition looks a bit different: `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"`)

Then you can use JSF tags with the prefixes `h`or `f` and Primefaces tags with the prefix `p`:

```
<h:inputText .../>
<p:calendar .../>
```